# If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ has all directional derivatives $\forall x \in U$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)=0$. So $f$ is a constant

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open and connected set. If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ has all the directional derivatives at every point $x \in U$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)=0$ for all $v$. Prove $f$ is a constant function.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Let's fix $a \in U$. By hypothesis $f$ has all the directional derivatives at every point $x \in U$, so $f|_{[a,b]}$ is a continuous function for all $[a,b] \subset U$ ($\textbf{Can I affirm what I said?}$) then by $\textbf{Mean value theorem}$ in several variables we have $$f(b)-f(a)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a+\theta v)$$but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)=0$ forall $v$, so $$f(b)-f(a)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a+\theta v)=0 \quad \implies \quad f(b)-f(a)=0 \quad \iff f(b)=f(a)$$
Now, forall $x \in U$ since $U$ is a connected set, so $x$ can be linked to a point $a$ by means of a polygon contained in $U$, with vertices $a_{0}=a,a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}=x$. Then we have successively $f(x)=\cdots=f(a_{1})=f(a)$. So $f(x)=f(a)$, $\forall x \in U$, it is mean $f$ is a constant function. $\Box$

Comment: Consider asking a question, that makes it easier to answer. Is there something in your proof you have doubts about? Also the title is akwardly phrased in my opinion, qualifying but not using $v$ for example.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is now correct. Note that it is enough to prove $f$ is locally constant, which can be done in the same way you presented since open sets are locally convex.
The continuity, and differentiability, of $f|_{[a,b]}$ is given by the fact that $v(t) = a + t(b-a)$ is continuous and differentiable and so $f \circ v$ is a differentiable function in one variable on $[0,1]$, with derivative same as what you presented.